# Update C# MongoDB

Tags: c#, mongodb

Решил попробовать MongoDB но застрял на методе Update

Есть такая модель, получаю её из xml

```
    [XmlRoot("CurrencyRates")]
    public class CurrencyRatesResponse : BaseStatusError
    {
        [BsonId]
        [XmlIgnore]
        public ObjectId RateId { get; set; }

        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "Name")]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "Date")]
        public string Date { get; set; }

        [XmlElement(ElementName = "Currency")]
        public List<CurrencyResponse> Currencies { get; set; }
    }

    public class CurrencyResponse
    {
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "ISOCode")]
        public string ISOCode { get; set; }

        public int Nominal { get; set; }
        public string Value { get; set; }
    }
```

При insert получаю такой документ в MongoDb

```
   {
    "_id": {"$oid": "5f54e7bea7708875d4a0e57a"},
    "Currencies": [
      {
        "ISOCode": "USD",
        "Nominal": 1,
        "Value": "78,7300"
      },
      {
        "ISOCode": "EUR",
        "Nominal": 1,
        "Value": "93,3698"
      },
      {
        "ISOCode": "KZT",
        "Nominal": 1,
        "Value": "0,1871"
      },
      {
        "ISOCode": "RUB",
        "Nominal": 1,
        "Value": "1,0472"
      }
    ],
    "Date": "07.09.2020",
    "Name": "Daily Exchange Rates"
  }
```

Не могу разобраться как обновить элемент `Currencies`
Пробовал так:

```
        public void Update<T>(string table, string isoCode, string value, ObjectId id)
        {
            var collection = _db.GetCollection<T>(table);
            var filter = Builders<T>.Filter.Eq("RateId", id);
            
            var update = Builders<T>.Update.Set(isoCode, value);

            collection.UpdateOneAsync(filter, update);
        }
```

Заполняю так:

```
    foreach (var item in result.Currencies)
    {
         mongoDb.Update<CurrencyRatesResponse>("CurrencyRate", item.ISOCode, item.Value,
                            resultAll.RateId);
    }
```

Но не получилось ( Думаю проблема в этой строке `var update = Builders<T>.Update.Set(isoCode, value);`
Так как не где не указывается элемент `Currencies`, но в Set принимаются только два параметра.

Пробовал так:

```
public void Update<T>(string table, string isoCode, string value, ObjectId id)
{
    var collection = _db.GetCollection<T>(table);
    var filter = Builders<T>.Filter.Eq("RateId", id);
    
    var update = Builders<T>.Update.Set("Currencies", new BsonDocument(
    {
        {"ISOCode" , isoCode},
        {"Value", value}
    })); // Если добавляешь последнюю скобку то начинает ругаться на то что лишний символ (;)
    

    collection.UpdateOneAsync(filter, update);
}
```

Изменил на _id фильтр, сработало но данные добавил в элемент _id

public void Update(string table, string isoCode, string value, ObjectId id)
{
var collection = _db.GetCollection(table);
var filter = Builders.Filter.Eq("_id", id);

```
    var update = Builders<T>.Update.Set(isoCode, value);

    collection.UpdateOneAsync(filter, update);
}


{
    "_id": {"$oid": "5f54f9f5d12a1032a51890fb"},
    "Currencies": [
      {
        "ISOCode": "USD",
        "Nominal": 1,
        "Value": "78,7300"
      },
      {
        "ISOCode": "EUR",
        "Nominal": 1,
        "Value": "93,3698"
      },
      {
        "ISOCode": "KZT",
        "Nominal": 1,
        "Value": "0,1871"
      },
      {
        "ISOCode": "RUB",
        "Nominal": 1,
        "Value": "1,0472"
      }
    ],
    "Date": "07.09.2020",
    "EUR": "93,3698", // <-------------------
    "KZT": "0,1871", // <-------------------
    "Name": "Daily Exchange Rates",
    "RUB": "1,0472", // <-------------------
    "USD": "78,7300" // <-------------------
  }
```

Тоже не получилось (

Comment: Возможно нужно фильтровать не по RateId: `var filter = Builders<T>.Filter.Eq("RateId", id);`, по `_id`, проверьте вообще возвращает фильтр что-то

Comment: `Builders<T>.Update.Set(isoCode, value)` а тут вы в качесте isoCode точно передаете название колонки, а не значение? возможно должно быть так `Set("ISOCode", value)`

Comment: @Exploding Kitten Да, Данные приходят верные, Изменил решение, вместо `RateId сделал _id` но теперь он добавил данные не туда куда нужно.

Answer (score 1):

Нужно было передавать `List<T>` и указывать элемент `"Currencies"`

```
public void Update<T>(string table, string field,  List<T> value, ObjectId id)
{
    var collection = _db.GetCollection<T>(table);
    var filter = Builders<T>.Filter.Eq("_id", id);
    var update = Builders<T>.Update.Set(field, value);
    collection.UpdateOneAsync(filter, update);
}
```

---

```
_mongoDb.Update("CurrencyRateDaily", "Currencies", currenciesList, resultDb.Id);
```